# on react component change all of its classNames are moving to its parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

In my project, I have a component with the following JSX

```html
<div className={`${styles}`}>
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6 delivery-address">
        <h4>DELIVERY ADDRESS</h4>
        <UserAddress { ...this.props.address } className="address-card"/>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div className="ordrbtn"><Link to="/checkout/payment" className="nav-link"><button>CONTINUE</button></Link></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to move className 'delivery-address' to a separate component, my updated JSX is following

```html
<div className={`${styles}`}>
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="delivery-address">
          <h4>DELIVERY ADDRESS</h4>
          <UserAddress { ...this.props.address } className="address-card"/>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div className="ordrbtn"><Link to="/checkout/payment" className="nav-link"><button>CONTINUE</button></Link></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is the rendered output.

```html
<div class="_31MAPZTc542WUNd0EWgW4J">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 delivery-address">
                <div class="_7yign4RAIpkiKQ5sKM4I_ address-card ">
                    <h4>DELIVERY ADDRESS</h4>
                    <div class="_7yign4RAIpkiKQ5sKM4I_ address-card">
                        <!--UserAddressComponent-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

delivery-address className is replaced with UserAddress component className.

After restarting the server everything working as expected. the problem is, I need to restart the node server every time on component update.

**OS** : MacOS X v 10.13.2

**node**: v8.7.0

Any support is appreciated.

Comment: Its an issue with webpack, actually not webpack my configuration, it uses lots of memory, that's why it can not update className.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use className to set children class name. Try pass your class as un-saved keyword as props, like:

`<UserAddress { ...this.props.address } customClassName="address-card"/>`, then in UserAddress : `<element className={this.props.customClassName} />`

Comment: Actually i cannot change any className that already exist in an element, but i can create new element, if the new element is parent of a Component poping above mentioned issue. className change is showing up only after server restart.

Comment: If `UserAddress` is out from your code base you can achive your goal only by css that will catch the `UserAddress` main element...